# How to get the actual error in case of uncommitable transaction in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am calling an sp from another sp which is calling another sp from within.  For instance sp1->sp2->sp3
I have used TRY-CATCH in all of them.
I raise an error explicitly in the sp3 and then catch in try-catch and then raise it again, and catch it in sp2 and then raise it again and then catch it in sp3. This works fine.

However, when I add a BEGIN TRAN on the most outer sp which is sp1. I get The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction. error.

What I want is to capture the actual error that caused the problem instead of this error. This error message is the impact of the actual error. Why it simply does not tell me that actual error which made the current Transaction uncommitable?

I googled a lot and read many posts about this error and none of them answers my question because almost every answer or question is mainly about handling this error by using XACT_STATE to determine whether to roll back or commit the transaction. However, in my case I simply roll back in case of any error what so ever.

For instance
 BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

```
    EXEC sp2

    COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SELECT @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
```

For instance
I added this line in sp3
RAISERROR('Catching errors from sp3 for testing...', 11, 2)

Now calling sp1 inside a transaction should give me this particular error, so I can deal with it.

However, if I remove the BEGIN TRAN from the most outer sp3 then I get the actual error and works fine.

Comment: Can you simply remove the nested try/catch blocks? Then sp1 is the only place with a try/catch.

Comment: Using `TRY / CATCH` is a good start, in combination with `XACT_ABORT`. Beyond that, you may want to read [this](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) -- error handling in T-SQL is no simple matter. You still want to include a `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK` in there. "I simply roll back" is counting on T-SQL's behavior to be simple, which it's not.

Comment: Sean Lange - because these sps are already in the system and being used. I do not want to edit them by removing try-catches. They have been called from other locations too. Removing try-catch will break the system in some places which I cannot do.

Comment: -Jeroen Mostert Thanks for sharing the link. I will read it.

Comment: Gotcha, wasn't sure if these are stand alone which it sounds like they are. Was hoping for the easy path. :)

Comment: Sean Lange - no problem. Thanks